# Where are the icons from?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, icons, font-awesome

I use a Flutter project from GitHub to learn Dart/Flutter. But now I have a problem, because I don't know where the icons come from!

This is the code snippet:

```
Icon(Icons.search,color: Colors.black,),
```

I want to know where the icon come from and how I can put there a FontAwesome Icon instead: https://fontawesome.com/icons/copy?style=regular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter `Icons` is bundles into the framework. You can check all the availabel icons [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html).

To use `Font Awesome` icons, check out available font awesome icon package for flutter [here](https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter).

Hope that helps!